# rxjs custom retryWhen strategy with auto incremented delay not working properly

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

I'm trying to create a custom `retryWhen` strategy which attempts to `retry` N times with X delay in-between and fail afterwards. To some extent the [learnrxjs.io](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/retrywhen.html) example is exactly what I'm looking for.

Unfortunately there is an issue with this code which I can't seem to figure how to resolve.
In my case, the observable can fail randomly - you can have `2 successful` attempts and then `2 unsuccessful` attempts. After a while the subscription will automatically complete, because the `retryAttempt`s will exceed the maximum although that has not happened in practice.

To better understand the issue I've created a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-retry-strategy-issue?embed=1&file=index.ts&hideExplorer=1&devtoolsheight=50)

The response will be:

```
  Attempt 1: retrying in 1000ms
  0
  1
  Attempt 2: retrying in 2000ms
  Attempt 3: retrying in 3000ms
  0
  1
  We are done!
```

But it should actually be

```
  Attempt 1: retrying in 1000ms
  0
  1
  Attempt 1: retrying in 1000ms <-- notice counter starts from 1
  Attempt 2: retrying in 2000ms
  0
  1
  Attempt 1: retrying in 1000ms <-- notice counter starts from 1
  0
  1
  Attempt 1: retrying in 1000ms <-- notice counter starts from 1
  Attempt 2: retrying in 2000ms
  0
  1
  ... forever
```

I feel like I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 2):

I think the example given in the docs is written for an Observable that only emits once and then completes, such as an http get.  It is assumed that if you want to get more data then you will subscribe again which will reset the counter inside `genericRetryStrategy`.  If, however, you now want to apply this same strategy to a long-running observable whose stream won't complete unless it gives an error (such as you have with `interval()`), then you'll need to modify `genericRetryStrategy()` to be told when the counter needs to be reset.

This could be done a number of ways, I have given a simple example in this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-so-q-58383112?file=index.ts) based off of what you said you were trying to accomplish.  Note that I also changed your logic slightly to more match what you said you were trying to do which is have '2 successful attempts and then 2 unsuccessful attempts'.  The important bits though are modifying the error object that is thrown into `genericRetryStrategy()` to communicate the current count of failed attempts so it can react appropriately.

Here is the code copied here for completeness:

```
import { timer, interval, Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { map, switchMap, tap, retryWhen, delayWhen, mergeMap, shareReplay, finalize, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

console.clear();

interface Err {
  status?: number;
  msg?: string;
  int: number;
}

export const genericRetryStrategy = ({
  maxRetryAttempts = 3,
  scalingDuration = 1000,
  excludedStatusCodes = []
}: {
  maxRetryAttempts?: number,
  scalingDuration?: number,
  excludedStatusCodes?: number[]
} = {}) => (attempts: Observable<any>) => {
  return attempts.pipe(
    mergeMap((error: Err) => {
      // i here does not reset and continues to increment?
      const retryAttempt = error.int;

      // if maximum number of retries have been met
      // or response is a status code we don't wish to retry, throw error
      if (
        retryAttempt > maxRetryAttempts ||
        excludedStatusCodes.find(e => e === error.status)
      ) {
        return throwError(error);
      }
      console.log(
        `Attempt ${retryAttempt}: retrying in ${retryAttempt *
          scalingDuration}ms`
      );
      // retry after 1s, 2s, etc...
      return timer(retryAttempt * scalingDuration);
    }),
    finalize(() => console.log('We are done!'))
  );
};

let int = 0;
let err: Err = {int: 0};
//emit value every 1s
interval(1000).pipe(
  map((val) => {
    if (val > 1) {
      //error will be picked up by retryWhen
      int++;
      err.msg = "equals 1";
      err.int = int;
      throw err;
    }
    if (val === 0 && int === 1) {
      err.msg = "greater than 2";
      err.int = 2;
      int=0;
      throw err;
    }
    return val;
  }),
  retryWhen(genericRetryStrategy({
    maxRetryAttempts: 3,
    scalingDuration: 1000,
    excludedStatusCodes: [],
  }))
).subscribe(val => {
  console.log(val)
});
```

To me this is still very imperative, but without understanding the problem you are trying to solve more deeply, I can't currently think of a more declarative approach...

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I might have unintentionally mislead you with the `if/else`s. The purpose was to simulate the scenario. In essence the `strategy` should reconnect (with delay) and give up if it fails for `5 consecutive times`. However the observable completes incorrectly because the `i` variable from `mergeMap(error, i)` does not reset to `0` after a successful attempt. So if you have 4 consecutive failures, a successful connection and then a failure - the observable `complete`s whereas it should continue with 4 more times until it gives up.

Comment: The `i` variable not resetting is what I was getting at with my first paragraph in my answer - as written, it will only "reset to zero" upon a new Subscribe.  In your example however, you are using a long running Observable which emits multiple values. For your real use case (not this contrived example), does your actual source Observable complete after one emission (such as an http get)?

Comment: It does not - it's an `EventSource`

Comment: I actually managed to solve it by [reading the docs](https://rxjs.dev/guide/v6/pipeable-operators#build-your-own-operators-easily)... [This](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-retry-strategy-issue-sc6nyn?file=index.ts) version seems to be solving the issue for me.

Comment: Ok, glad you got it sorted out.  :)